# Is there a way to check a web server against all kind of the CVE?

Tags: security, vulnerability

Instead of tracking all of the CVE items from [cvedetails](https://www.cvedetails.com/) or [cve.mitre](https://cve.mitre.org/) and analyzing/determining if the web server system identified with specific OS version, specific kernel, specific software version, specific configuration (conf files, access privileges, and like), and of course specific hardware is vulnerable ...
is there some way to check the system against them all?

Comment: if it's java/maven, you can use the OWASP maven plugin and it will check for you.

Comment: great, I will check it soon @NeilMcGuigan

Answer (score 2):

if you have valuable property, the OpenVas worth a try, free and web GUI integrated.
checkout http://www.openvas.org/  document

Answer (score 1):

I found this resource signed by Intel: https://github.com/ikeydoherty/cve-check-tool

(think it was the Irish department of Intel I heard of them before) that can provide the insight and check the system against the common known vulnerabilities.

Haven't checked the system yet, but saw being said in there it may catch also some false positives, and it is relative resource intensive.